# Drastic CTE query speed degradation on actions in outer select

Tags: sql, performance, common-table-expression

I have a complex report (Similar to example below) it returns with only 52 items in 42 seconds (Slow but does complex joins) it drastically slows down when I do the following:

1. Add a column in the outer select to get a serialized list of items for
   each item in the result (Adds 150 seconds) - See function.
2. Insert result into a variable table (Adds 120 seconds), I though hoped flattening it would reduce the (1) issue but no cigar.

How I understand the execution is that the where is executed first then logic in the select (Should only be done for the 52 result items). However if I run that exact 52 items with the (1) **scenario it only takes 7 seconds vs the added 150 when using it on the outer CTE select**.

Why could this be and how can I add the column without the bloated execution time?

```
CREATE FUNCTION PriorShippers
(
    @customerId nchar(5)
)
RETURNS varchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return varchar(500);

    with data as
    (
        select distinct S.CompanyName from Customers C
          join Orders O on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
          join Shippers S on O.ShipVia = S.ShipperID
          where C.CustomerID = @customerId

    ) select @return = STUFF((select CompanyName + ' ' from data FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'')

    return @return
END
```

The query (I used Northwind database - [Install Instructions here](http://businessimpactinc.com/install-northwind-database) for SQL 2012)

```
DECLARE @categories TABLE
(
    Name varchar(100),
    SourceCountry varchar(100)
);
insert into @categories VALUES ('Seafood', 'US');
insert into @categories VALUES ('Beverages', 'US');
insert into @categories VALUES ('Condiments', 'US');
insert into @categories VALUES ('Dairy Products', 'India');
insert into @categories VALUES ('Grains/Cereals', 'India');

with data as
(
    select C.CustomerID, C.CompanyName,
        (CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * from Orders O where O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID) THEN
            (select count(distinct CAT.CategoryID) from Orders O 
                join [Order Details] OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
                join Products P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
                join Categories CAT on P.CategoryID = CAT.CategoryID
             where EXISTS(select * from @categories where Name = CAT.CategoryName AND SourceCountry = 'US'))
        ELSE 0 END) as 'US Orders', 

        (CASE WHEN EXISTS(select * from Orders O where O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID) THEN
            (select count(distinct CAT.CategoryID) from Orders O 
                join [Order Details] OD on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
                join Products P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
                join Categories CAT on P.CategoryID = CAT.CategoryID
             where EXISTS(select * from @categories where Name = CAT.CategoryName AND SourceCountry = 'India'))
        ELSE 0 END) as 'India Orders'

    from Customers C

) select top 10 CompanyName, [US Orders], [India Orders]
    -- Below: Adding this have significant slow down
    , dbo.PriorShippers(CustomerID) 
    from data where [US Orders] > 0 Order By [US Orders]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a user-defined function for each selected row. In short, **don't do that.**

Move the code in the function into a DTE directly within the report.

Also, I noticed that the joins for your counts are identical. They look like prime candidates for a third DTE that you could simply join to to further improve the performance of the overall query.

Comment: Hi Mike, I cannot nest the selection because the function uses a CTE (The distinct select that must be serialized). I understand calling functions is generally not a good idea but that being said my concern is the massive jump in execution time. If I take that same result (52) items add them to a variable table select call user function as with CTE it only takes 7 seconds vs the additional 150 seconds. Also only selecting the values (without user function call) adds 120 seconds experienced in the example. I am trying to understand how the CTE outer select is different from a normal select.